# XPath expression causes self reference (loop)

Tags: xml, loops, xpath, conditional-statements, infopath2010

I attempting to use 2, mutually exclusing conditional XPath expressions in conjunction with the "|" command to evaluate the appropriate XML node. I am using InfoPath 2010.

When I open my form using the example XML below I am informed that there is a loop present in my "rules" - i.e one of my XPath expressions is flip-flopping between target nodes indefinitely. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Here is the XPath expression:

`//my:SPIF_Info_Repeater[1 = count(following-sibling::my:SPIF_Info_Repeater)]//my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number[text()] | //my:Chargeable_Object_Number[text() and not(//my:SPIF_Info_Repeater[1 = count(following-sibling::my:SPIF_Info_Repeater)]//my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number[text()])]`

I believe that InfoPath uses the `<my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number>` as the "Current" node value when the expression is being evaluated in the form. It is the default value for that node.

Here is my target XML. Apologies that it is so nested; I've stripped out everything that could be sensitive but left the involved node structure intact.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-infoPathSolution PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="" name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:PPIF-Forms:-myXSD-2011-05-05T19-56-08" productVersion="14.0.0" solutionVersion="1.0.0.1090" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?>
<?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?>
    <my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:tns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-05-05T19:56:08" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
        <my:MasterSection>
            <my:ActualProjectHider/>
                <my:SPIF_Hider>
                    <my:SPIF_Info_Repeater_Group>
                        <my:SPIF_Info_Repeater>
                            <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items_Group>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>    
                            </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items_Group> 
                            <my:SPIF_Data>   
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number>APPLES</my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number>
                            </my:SPIF_Data>                 
                        </my:SPIF_Info_Repeater>
                        <my:SPIF_Info_Repeater> 
                            <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items_Group>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>              
                                    <my:Amount_Hider/>       
                                </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items>    
                            </my:SPIF_Chargeable_Line_Items_Group> 
                            <my:SPIF_Data>
                                <my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number>BANANAS</my:SPIF_Chargeable_Object_Number>    
                            </my:SPIF_Data>                 
                        </my:SPIF_Info_Repeater>    
                    </my:SPIF_Info_Repeater_Group>
                </my:SPIF_Hider>
                <my:ProjectTypeInfo/>
                <my:AdminPass>
                    <my:ViewSwitcher/>
                    <my:AdminPassText></my:AdminPassText>
                </my:AdminPass>
                <my:SPIFInitErrorHider/>
        </my:MasterSection>
    </my:myFields>
```

It took me quite some time to isolate this issue; there *must* be something in my XPath expression that is causing iteration between the nodes.